# C# to JSON serialization using JSON.Net

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I have a C# List which looks like this:

```
var reqUsers = from user in users
    select new
    {
        username = user.username,
        firstName = user.firstName,
        lastName = user.lastName,
        email = user.email
    };
```

I use the below to convert / serialize to JSON ( Newtonsoft.JSON ):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqUsers);
```

With the above code I get a json string like this:

```
[{ username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" },
 { username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "al@test.com" },
 { username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" } ]
```

however here is what I need to get : since I am using handlebars templating -

```
var testdata = {
  users: [
  { username: "alan", firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", email: "alan@test.com" },
  { username: "allison", firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House", email: "al@test.com" },
  { username: "ryan", firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson", email: "ryan@test.com" } ]
```

How can use the Serializer to name the JSON array as above ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { users = reqUsers });
```

Comment: When accessing the joson in the JS I had to use   'var thejson = @Html.Raw(json);'     to not have issues with the quotes

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var json= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(reqUsers);
```

Comment: This is using the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace instead of Netwonsoft.Json as the original poster was using. It's a valid option however.

Comment: thanks, This is good for byte array in object. prevent byte array convert to base64