# How to make string to JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

[ASK] C# Xamarin JSOn

```
String a = "{\"success\":1,\"message\":\"successfully created.\"}";
string b = "{"success":1,"message":"successfully created."}";
```

how to get value success and message in JSON ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the relationship between `a` and `b` in the above? If your question is asking how to convert an object into JSON, JsonConvert.SerializeObject looks promising. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294963/json-net-serialize-object-with-root-name or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843446/c-sharp-to-json-serialization-using-json-net

Answer (score 1):

Given the class model of (via http://jsonutils.com):

```
public class Example
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = "{\"success\":1,\"message\":\"successfully created.\"}";
var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(a);
Console.WriteLine($"{example.success} : {example.message}");
```

Output:

```
1 : successfully created.
```