# How to get property value that is a class itself within a class method

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes

I want to create some classes, that have to look a certain way (the way shown in my example).

Some of the class properties are classes (or structs) themselves.

I want to write a method within my classes that get the property values of all the properties that are Structs and write them to a string.

So this is what my classes look like:

```
public class car
{
   public string brand { get; set; }
   public tire _id { get; set; }
   public string GetAttributes()
   {
      Type type = this.GetType();
      PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
      foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
      if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("_"))
      {
         //I want to write the actual value of the property here!
         string nested_property_value = ...
         return nested_property_value;
      }
   }
}
```

this is what my structs look like:

```
 public struct tire
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
 }
```

this would be the Main Program:

```
tire mynewtire = new tire()
{
   id = 5
};

car mynewcar = new car()
{
   _id = mynewtire
};
```

How can I create a working method to get these property attributes?

Comment: Have you considered JSON serialisation to convert it to a string? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843446/c-sharp-to-json-serialization-using-json-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will get you started. I recommend you look at other serialisation methods (such as JSON) as well.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public class car
    {
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public tire _id { get; set; }

        public string GetAttributes()
        {
            var type = this.GetType();
            var returnValue = "";
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                // Look at properties of the car
                if (propertyInfo.Name.Contains("_") && propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType &&
                    !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
                {
                    var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);

                    var propType = propValue.GetType();
                    var propProperties = propType.GetProperties();

                    foreach (var propPropertyInfo in propProperties)
                    {
                        // Now get the properties of tire
                        // Here I just concatenate to a string - you can tweak this
                        returnValue += propPropertyInfo.GetValue(propValue).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

    public struct tire
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mynewtire = new tire()
            {
                id = 5
            };

            var mynewcar = new car()
            {
                _id = mynewtire
            };
            Console.WriteLine(mynewcar.GetAttributes());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```